# Как вставить текст в textarea через webview

Tags: java, android, html, android-webview

Есть `Webview`, он грузит страницу html в которой есть форма с `textarea`... и есть кнопка..

Нужно чтоб при нажатии на кнопку в textarea вставлялся определенный текст, допустим, слово "Привет".

Как это сделать на java?

И сразу вопрос, как потом весь текст (дописанный пользователем) из `textarea` "достать", и поместить в `String` строку?

Comment: Без редактирования html страницы вряд ли возможно. У вас доступ к этому html есть?

Comment: Да доступ есть (страница в папке "assets" приложения)

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый ^_^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Чтобы передать что-то со страницы в Java часть необходимо взаимодействия с html страницей настроить.

1. Включить выполнение JS: `webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);`.
2. Создать класс-интерфейс между Java и JS:

   ```
   public class WebViewJavaScriptInterface{

       private Context context;


       public WebViewJavaScriptInterface(Context context){
           this.context = context;
       }

       @JavascriptInterface
       public void getText(String message){
           Toast.makeText(context, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
   }
   ```
3. Установить связь: `webView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebViewJavaScriptInterface(this), "MyJavaHandler");`.
4. Теперь в JavaScript части на странице вы можете вызывать метод `getText` и он будет обрабатываться в `getText` методе класса `WebViewJavaScriptInterface`:

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
          MyJavaHandler.getText("текст, который вы хотите прокинуть в Java");
   </script>
   ```

Для передачи из Java в JS:

1. Определить функцию в JS:

   ```
   function callFromActivity(msg){
          // здесь строка, переданная из Java
   }
   ```
2. В Java части вызвать `webView.loadUrl("javascript:callFromActivity(\"Привет\")");`

Comment: Это я понял... Вы дали пример как из html страницы передать информацию в java.. А мне нужно наоборот... Из java передать на html страницу, и вставить в textarea!

Comment: @Вадим обновил ответ.