# Взаимодействие java и html5

Tags: java, android, html

Нужно поставить обработчиком кода метод из java. Javascrypt не поможет. Читал, что можно через `<%@page import="..." %>`. Но браузер и эмулятор не воспринимают эти теги и просто пишут текст

Comment: `<%@ ... %>` - это директива [JSP](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSP). Нужен сервер, который умеет их обрабатывать.

Comment: Подробнее, пожалуйста. Я должен скачать библиотеку jsp? Как в случае с Vue.js, например

Comment: Меня смущает _эмулятор_ - пишете под андроид?

Comment: Да, я пишу под андроид

Comment: @Дмитрий нет, вы должны выполнить JSP-файл на сервере типа Tomcat, Glassfish, Wildfly, WebSphere или WebLogic. В Android не запустить JSP. По приведённой мной ссылке это подробнейшим образом описано.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как вставить текст в textarea через webview](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/735942/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82-%d0%b2-textarea-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-webview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вам нужно вызвать java-метод из js-кода страницы, можно использовать [JavascriptInterface](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html#BindingJavaScript).

В коде android-приложения:

```
public class WebAppInterface {
    Context mContext;

    WebAppInterface(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void showToast(String toast) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
webView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "Android");
```

В коде страницы:

```
<input type="button" value="Say hello" onClick="showAndroidToast('Hello Android!')" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function showAndroidToast(toast) {
        Android.showToast(toast);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Огромное вам спасибо!