# Как получить значение из webview?

Tags: java, android, webview, android-webview

Заготовка:

```
WebView myWebView;
String msg;
........
myWebView = findViewById(R.id.myWebView);
WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

html страница (код со скриптом):

```
<input type="button" value="Say hello" onClick="showAndroidToast('Hello Android!')" />
<script type="text/javascript">
function showAndroidToast(toast) { Android.showToast(toast); }
```

Как теперь это все связать, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку в html странице, значение 'Hello Android!' присвоилось переменной msg?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Взаимодействие java и html5](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/739110/%d0%92%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%b9%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b5-java-%d0%b8-html5)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как вставить текст в textarea через webview](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/735942/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82-%d0%b2-textarea-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-webview)